Btrfs scrub of filesystem with a file that is constantly being written to?
Imagine this:
I have any kind of image file that I use as a virtual hard drive of a VM. And now consider, that for whatever reason I 24/7 write in this VM guest and hence to this image file - will the btrfs scrub of the VM host be able to completely check the image for consistency? Of course I understand, that it will miss everything, that is written after the scrubbing action, but can it validate all information (especially) including the constantly rewritten image file correctly, predictably and reliably, or will I have to shut the VM down to halt all writes to the file before the scrub?
Sorry if I overlook something obvious, but this is important for something that I need to implement into a productive system and I cannot really find reliable sources on this matter, it just sounds like opinion.


Btrfs is primarily a "copy on write" filesystem, that is, files (and metadata) are never overwritten in-place – a new chunk of data is written elsewhere, complete with checksums, then pointers within metadata are switched from reflecting all old data to reflecting all new data. (This means that at any point it can have a consistent view of a specific 'version' of the entire file system, which allows it to quickly create snapshots.)
Scrub doesn't use snapshots, but the CoW "no in-place overwrite" design still means that it will always see individual blocks being consistent with themselves; i.e. it will never see a block with new data but old checksum.
CoW of course leads to a bit of fragmentation for VM disk images, so if you have set the NOCOW flag on the images, then they will be overwritten in place – but they also won't have any data checksums (and no metadata updates for each write), therefore scrub isn't nearly as useful on them anyway.

Still, as far as I can gather from the Linux source code, it seems that scrub is momentarily paused while Btrfs is writing out a transaction and resumed at the end of the transaction, allowing the scrub process to see a consistent view of e.g. raid1-mirrored blocks even for nocow files – and by extent also a consistent view of everything else.
int btrfs_commit_transaction(struct btrfs_trans_handle *trans)
{
        [...]
        btrfs_scrub_pause(fs_info);
        [...]
        btrfs_scrub_continue(fs_info);
        [...]
}



